# Error when adding localizable string file

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

```
   Copy Strings File Error Group
 Localizable.strings:0: error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

I added Localizable string and add 15 different language string file from info section.

The app was running before adding all localization to it. Not sure what causing this error.

Any help

Answer (score 0):

make sure all the .string files contains format of translation as below:

```
"key"="translation";
"nav_profile"="Мой профайл";
```

missing semicolon or any other different format than above format in any line of any string file can generate this error.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. The tool used for translating add comments after each phrase. But somehow one phrase did not put // before commented line which caused this issue.